# D3D12 project: dereferencing a nullptr

Tags: c++, wrl, directx-12

I am working with the Microsoft samples from their GitHub page and even though my code is based off theirs I am not reaching the same result.
Both projects have these ComPtrs yet in mine they all are null (0x0000000000000000) while in the sample they work perfectly fine.

```
ComPtr<IDXGISwapChain3> m_swapChain;
ComPtr<ID3D12Device> m_device;
ComPtr<ID3D12Resource> m_renderTargets[FrameCount];
ComPtr<ID3D12CommandAllocator> m_commandAllocator;
ComPtr<ID3D12CommandQueue> m_commandQueue;
ComPtr<ID3D12DescriptorHeap> m_rtvHeap;
ComPtr<ID3D12PipelineState> m_pipelineState;
ComPtr<ID3D12GraphicsCommandList> m_commandList;
```

Specifically this line causes the debugger to break.

```
ThrowIfFailed(m_device->CreateCommandQueue(&queueDesc, IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_commandQueue)));
```

Edit: My code was incorrectly creating m_device which caused the error.

Comment: You have only shown the variable declarations, there is no way for anyone to know why they haven't been set to non-null values. You need to show more of your code.

Comment: Where is the code that initializes `m_device` before calling `m_device->CreateCommandQueue()`?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are getting a failed HRESULT back from `CreateCommandQueue`. You should set the debugger to break on exceptions (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x85tt0dd.aspx)). Alternatively, you can rewrite it to:

```
HRESULT hr = m_device->CreateCommandQueue(&queueDesc, IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_commandQueue));
ThrowIfFailed(hr);
```

And set a debug break-point on the `HRESULT hr = ...` line.

> As someone noted, make sure you have checked for all possible failure conditions before this point. For some robust code for creating a Direct3D 12 device, see [DeviceResources](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/DeviceResources) or the [VS Direct3D 12 Game templates](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/12/17/direct3d-game-visual-studio-templates-redux/)

Comment: This assumes `m_device` was initialized to a non-null value to begin with.

Comment: True enough. As I've stated in many a SO thread, you have to check the return value of anything that has an ``HRESULT`` for failure using ``SUCCEDED`` or ``FAILED`` macro or something like [ThrowIfFailed](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ThrowIfFailed). You can't ignore the return value.